# What format are GCC's object files in?

Tags: gcc, object-files

I assembled an assembly file in GCC under Windows like so:

```
as main.s -o main.o
```

And now I have the following object file:

```
4C 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 
00 00 05 01 2E 74 65 78 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 8C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 30 60 2E 64 61 74 
61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
40 00 30 C0 2E 62 73 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 30 C0 C3 90 90 90 
2E 66 69 6C 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE FF 00 00 
67 01 66 61 6B 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 2E 74 65 78 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
01 00 00 00 03 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2E 64 61 74 61 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2E 62 73 73 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 03 01 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
04 00 00 00
```

I'd like to look inside this file to try and understand how object files are put together. Where can I find a format specification for whatever format this file is?

Comment: Hint to get you going: Search the internet for the first few bytes (4C 01). Or get a linux machine to invoke `file` on the object file, often useful aswell. Not sure what the windows equivalent is.

Comment: Well according to the [Online Dissasembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/), it's a "80386 COFF executable not stripped - version 30821", but it doesn't seem to fit [this](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/coff.pdf) COFF format specification at all.